# Cannot create an instance of class SharedPrefViewModel in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, sharedpreferences, viewmodel

I have an app where I'm using SharedPreferences.
When I try to get the saved name this error occurs:
**java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.meetme.viewmodel.SharedPrefViewModel**

What could be wrong in code below? Any ideas?

**SharedPrefViewModel class:**

```
class SharedPrefViewModel(context: Context): ViewModel() {
    private var sharedPrefRepository: SharedPrefRepository = SharedPrefRepository(context.applicationContext)
 
    fun putString(name: String) {
        sharedPrefRepository.putString(name)
    }
    fun getString() : String? {
        return sharedPrefRepository.getString() <-- here is the error
    }
}
```

**SharedPrefRepository class:**

```
class SharedPrefRepository(context: Context) {
    private val pref: SharedPreferences =
        context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

    var name: String?
    get() = pref.getString(PREF_LOGGED_IN, "")
    set(value) = pref.edit().putString(PREF_LOGGED_IN, value).apply()
    
    fun putString(name: String) {
        this.name = name
    }

    fun getString() : String? {
        return this.name
    }
}
```

**Composable, where I'm using prefs to save a name:**

```
@Composable
fun BasicInfoScreen(navController: NavHostController) {
    var context = LocalContext.current.applicationContext
    val sharedPrefViewModel = SharedPrefViewModel(context)

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.White)
            .padding(16.dp)
    ) {
        ...
        Button(
            onClick = {
                sharedPrefViewModel.putString("default") <---- here
                navController.navigate(RootGraphItem.Location.route)
            },
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(50.dp)
                .background(Color(0xFF0090FF)),
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = Color(0xFF0090FF))
        ) {
            Text(text = "Next", style = TextStyle(color = Color.White))
        }
    }
}
```

**Composable that gets a value from prefs:**

```
@Composable
fun LocationScreen(navController: NavHostController) {
    val sharedPrefViewModel: SharedPrefViewModel = viewModel()

    println(sharedPrefViewModel.getString()) <-- get name

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.White)
            .padding(16.dp)
    ) {
       ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All ViewModels are created using a Factory. If your ViewModel constructor doesn't fit something that the **default factory** can handle, then you have to create your own `ViewModelProvider.Factory` implementation that can create your ViewModel, and you must pass it to the `viewModel()` function in your composable.

You **must never** directly call your ViewModel constructor except inside its factory! This: `val sharedPrefViewModel = SharedPrefViewModel(context)` will cause problems because your ViewModel is not created through the ViewModelProvider, so it is not *registered* and so it will not have a proper lifecycle and it will not use a single shared instance by different screens/composables that use it.

The default factory is only capable of creating instances of your ViewModel if your ViewModel constructor's arguments are one of the following:

- `constructor()` Empty constructor (no arguments)
- `constructor(savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle)`
- `constructor(application: Application)`

  - Also requires that you subclass `AndroidViewModel`, not just `ViewModel`.
- `constructor(application: Application, savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle)`

  - Also requires that you subclass `AndroidViewModel`, not just `ViewModel`.

Notice, your constructor takes a single `Context` argument, so it doesn't fit any of the above. If you want to avoid having to create a factory, which is a lot of boilerplate, I would change your class as follows so it fits the third one above:

```
class SharedPrefViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private val context: Context = application.applicationContext

    //...
}
```

And don't forget to fix the line where you called your constructor instead of calling `viewModel()`!

Comment: How can I get the application parameter from the composable functions?

Comment: You don't need it! Just create your view model using `viewModel()` since you must never call your ViewModel constructor, like I said. The default factory will take care of passing it the application instance.

Comment: Omg! Thank you so much. Works now, I missed the last line in your answer. You're the best!